# hibernate criteria query

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have the following query sql query:

```
select * from Articles ar
left join ArticleTeamRelationships atr on atr.ArticleId = ar.ArticleId
left join Team te on te.TeamId = atr.TeamId 
inner join ArticleCategoryRelationships acr on acr.ArticleId = ar.ArticleId
inner join ArticleCategory ac on ac.CategoryId = acr.CategoryId
where ac.CategoryId = 3 
and ((te.TeamId in (1) and ar.TeamReadOnly = 1) or te.TeamId is null)
```

This is what I've written so far:

```
Criteria childCriteriaCategory = criteria.createCriteria("articleCategory", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);
childCriteriaCategory.add(Restrictions.like("categoryId", categoryId));
Criteria childCriteriaTeam = criteria.createCriteria("team", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN);       
childCriteriaTeam.add(Restrictions.in("teamId", teamId));
Criterion teamReadOnly = Restrictions.eq("teamReadOnly", true);
criteria.add(teamReadOnly);
```

How can I write the "and" inside the first brackets and the "or"?

Comment: Have you checked this out? http://www.roseindia.net/hibernate/examples/criteria/hibernate-criteria-and-or.html

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. My problem is that I need to put the "and" between two tables, and I don't know how to do this.

Comment: use alias names to refer to the table. You don't need all these variables. It is much more readable when written in fluent style.

Comment: Can you pleas give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you want for

```
((te.TeamId in (1) and ar.TeamReadOnly = 1) or te.TeamId is null)
```

will be something like:

```
Restrictions.or(
    Restrictions.and(
        Restrictions.in(x, x), Restrictions.eq(x, x)
    ),
    Restrictions.eq(x,x)
)
```

Comment: Just came across this question - I have code exactly like this here, only the parenthesis never actually get included - so the SQL query generates totally flat and yields invalid results. At least - this is under PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a first `and` to do the join and a second one like:

```
//pseudo code
tablea.foreignId = id

tableb.id = id
```

Comment: I understand the logic, but I don't know how to write this in Java. Can you please give me an example in java code?